# Maximize the expected values of a function with constrain

Tags: probability, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Consider $p_1,p_2,...p_N$ are probabilities arranged in ascending order.
$n_1, n_2,...n_N$ are numbers which are arranged in geometric progression.

I want to Maximize E= $\sum\limits_{i=1}^N p_i\cdot n_i$, subject to the constraint $\sum\limits_{i=1}^N n_i=L$

Here, $ n_1=a, n_2=ar, n_3=ar^2, ...,n_N=ar^{N-1} $

Hence,
$a+ar+ ar^2+...+ar^{N-1}=L$ and

$E=p_1*a+p_2*ar+p_3*ar^2+..+p_N*ar^{N-1}$

How to find values of $a$ and $r$ which will maximize E.

Thanks,
Kunal

Comment: Look at linear and nonlinear programming. It should be a start.